# add an array of objects to state in a reducer

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm creating multiple records at once with a rest api. The `action.payload` contains the `id` of each record that was created, returned from the server. What would be the best way to add the id to each record I just created in my reducer?

This is what I have so far. I'm not getting any errors, but the records are not appearing in my app after they are created.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [] };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {

case POST_TERRITORY_GEOGRAPHY_MASS:

let territories= action.territories.records;

action.payload.then(request => {

  for(var i = 0; i < request.data.results.length; i++) {
    territories[i].Id = request.data.results[i].id
  }

  return {
    ...state.all, territories
       ????
  }
})
}
```

Are you able to update state in a reducer inside a `then` part of a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't send a promise to the reducer. Async would require 2 actions. The first action is the act of requesting. It calls the async operation as well as telling your reducer the first action. This is used to toggle the state to "loading".

When that async operation completes, it calls the second action carrying the results. This action will then arrive to your reducer, removing your app from the "loading" state and updating it with results.

See [Redux's Reddit API example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html) and look for the `fetchPosts` function.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: in that example `redux-thunk` middleware has been used http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html#configurestorejs